# How to custom the location of the activeX warning bar via javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer

How to custom the location of the activeX warning bar via javascript .
I donot want to hide the warning information but want to change it . Such as the content or the location . Any good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is a core component of the browser. It's like asking if you can change the position of the File menu with Javascript*. Think of the security problems if websites could change this warning bar at will.

**I am not talking about XUL :)*